# Silverlight - Passing mouse coords from UI View to ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, mvvm, mousemove

I'm using Silverlight with MVVM (using Caliburn.Micro).
I've created a simple rectangle in the View as follows:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle2" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseMove] = [Action MouseMoved($eventArgs)]" Fill="#FFE2F5FF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Margin="195,43,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="195" />
```

In the ViewModel I have:

```
public void MouseMoved(MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
{
        var point = mouseEventArgs.GetPosition(null);
        String str = string.Format("({0}\t{1})",point.X,point.Y);
        MVVMCoords = str;
}
```

The coords that appear are absolute because I put null in GetPosition.
How can I make them relative to the rectangle? (So the top left corner of the rectangle is 0,0)
As far as I understand, this can be done with out the ViewModel knowing the UIElements in the View.

Thanks,
Guy

Comment: Normally I'd suggest just passing in `Rectangle2` into the `GetPosition` call (`var point = mouseEventArgs.GetPosition(Rectangle2);`) but you're saying you don't have a reference to that object? EDIT: Doesn't the mouse move event pass in a sender? Are you throwing that out when you attach the event? If so, keep the sender and pass that into the `GetPosition` call.

Comment: I can have a reference, but if i'm not mistaken, the rule is that the ViewModel doesn't know about the elements in the UI and vice versa. I'm trying to find a way to make the coords relative to the UIElement with out passing the UIElement. But now that I think about it, It is not that I am referring to a certain element on the UI, i'm casting to a general UIElement. What do you think?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, tracking the mouse position is part of the view anyway. The view would communicate the _relevant_ position down to the view model (if truly necessary). I don't think your "view" _must_ only exist as part of the XAML. Maybe it's _possible_ to do it, but I don't think it's worth bending over backwards for. I don't think it's a violation that when you receive a UI event, that you receive its _sender_ (in fact, that's _standard_). Have the View handle determining the relative coordinates, then send that value to your ViewModel.